# Apache ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: apache, chunked-encoding

Sometimes, for no real reason I get the following console message and a completely blank screen after deploying code to the server:

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

An Apache restart fixes it but I can't see why it happens. The file system changes but not any config. I've never encountered it when not doing a deployment, so something about the file system changing whilst apache is running seems to cause it.

The document root is a symlink (current/) to the latest release folder.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue.  I'm not certain it is tied to code deployment, but it might be.  Its a Symfony project, running on PHP 5.5

Comment: My best guess it that Apache doesn't like the document root changing, perhaps if a request is being dealt with during the symlink change as it only happens occasionally and since our traffic has increased.

Answer (score 5):

This might not be your problem, but it solved it for me so i'm going to throw it out there anyway - setting `opcache.fast_shutdown=0` fixed it.  It is disabled by default according to [the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) 
but had been enabled in our setup.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using the default opcache.ini and fast_shutdown was set to 1 even though the documentation still says it defaults to 0. documentation on the flag: http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.fast-shutdown

Comment: I spoke too soon, looks like I am still receiving the error

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with phpmyadmin. Try disabling your antivirus.

Comment: This saved my life, restarting the antivirus on my server solved this for me. Thanks for sharing.